# Creating a "grid" layout using ng-repeat

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

The situation I'm trying to solve is this and I'm a bit puzzled as to how this can be tackled. I'm using `ng-repeat` for each of the points I've stated here and I intend to use this in the final solution if possible.

- I have an array of objects, all the exact same format. (Safely assume this is true)
- Each object has a list of attributes.
- I wish to arrange these in a grid with >2 columns and there will be an arbitrarily large number of rows.
- Each grid location will display the attributes of the object in that location.
- The number of columns does not need to be dynamically changeable.

The >2 columns requirement is that I understand how to do a one or two column grid layout (one column is an unordered and unstyled list and two columns using the `ng-even` or `ng-odd` and using css to create a new line).

**So the question is basically this: for an array of size `N` and a column number of size `M` (`M<N`), can I create a grid of the `N` elements with `M` elements per row while still using `ng-repeat`?**

If possible, I'd rather not just insert a `<br>` every `M` elements - since I'm using `ng-repeat` each element is expected to have the attributes of the object as I define it in the `ng-repeat`, and I know that angular will deal with incorrect input but to exploit that doesn't seem like proper practice.

Also using a table leaves me in the same situation as before, I still need to do a different operation every `M` elements.

Is there a clean way to do this in angular?

It is worth noting that I'm also using `twitter-bootstrap` so I'll welcome css solutions too.

Thanks in advance and please tell me if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont really know if this is what you are looking for ( if not please provide an example - json data array is also fine ! )

Here is a plunk that displays a MxN data ( array! - you can make it object as well if you wish)

http://plnkr.co/edit/TgKA0cQ80Vo3vWztxFw4?p=preview

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! No idea why pre-processing it into a 2D array never crossed my mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue as well, unfortunately a table won't do the trick for my use case. It seems even with a 2D array ng-repeat tends to ignore `col-md-6` even inside a `row`.

Comment: This was originally for an old version of bootstrap, so unsure about the col-md-6. Is your browser wide enough for md-6 to apply?

Comment: <facepalm> I realized I was using the old bootstrap. Switching to v3 did the trick </facepalm>

Comment: Ha! There's your problem ;) best of luck!